# Configuration for running nutch unit tests in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, nutch

I have nutch set up for eclipse and can run and debug to my hearts content.  I can compile from eclipse or the command line, using ant.  I can test all modules individually.  However, when running the generic nutch download tests from the command line - e.g. ant test, I get a few failures in some of the (unmodified) modules.

My question: how do I run the unit tests from within eclipse so I can see where the tests are failing? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unit test in your project, you can right click and 'Run-as'. Select 'JUnit test' (or other test framework). This should initialize the unit test module in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, just figured that out :-)  Doh!